# I wrote a web counter, but how can I disable F5 to prevent the number increase?

Tags: php, web, counter

I have written a web counter, the counter gets the number get from count.txt and adds 1 when I visit the web.

But how can I prevent it from adding 1 when I refresh the page???

The code:

```
<?php
//Get User's IP
    if ($_SESSION['your_ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
        $_SESSION['your_ip']  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $addone = ture;
    }
    else {
        $addone = false;
    }
//Get the number stored in "count.txt"
    $fp = fopen("count.txt",'r');
    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $buf .= fgets($fp,1024);
    }
    fclose($fp);
//Convert $buf into number and add 1
    if ($addone == ture) {
        $buf = intval($buf) + 1;
    }
//Replace the number in count.txt by $buf
    $fp = fopen("count.txt",'w');
    fputs($fp,$buf);
    fclose($fp);
//Break $buf
    $num1 = intval($buf/100000000);
    $buf = $buf%100000000;
    $num2 = intval($buf/10000000);
    $buf = $buf%10000000;
    $num3 = intval($buf/1000000);
    $buf = $buf%1000000;
    $num4 = intval($buf/100000);
    $buf = $buf%100000;
    $num5 = intval($buf/10000);
    $buf = $buf%10000;
    $num6 = intval($buf/1000);
    $buf = $buf%1000;
    $num7 = intval($buf/100);
    $buf = $buf%100;
    $num8 = intval($buf/10);
    $buf = $buf%10;
    $num9 = intval($buf/1);
    $buf = $buf%1;
//Display result
    echo "<img src=\"elements/num_".$num1.".png\">";
    echo "<img src=\"elements/num_".$num2.".png\">";
    echo "<img src=\"elements/num_".$num3.".png\">";
    echo "<img src=\"elements/num_".$num4.".png\">";
    echo "<img src=\"elements/num_".$num5.".png\">";
    echo "<img src=\"elements/num_".$num6.".png\">";
    echo "<img src=\"elements/num_".$num7.".png\">";
    echo "<img src=\"elements/num_".$num8.".png\">";
    echo "<img src=\"elements/num_".$num9.".png\">";
?>
```

Comment: You don't "disable F5"! Never, ever! Wrong mindset!

Comment: @deceze Please tell that to twitter ;__;

Comment: You're also going to need a `session_start()` in there somewhere

Comment: @deceze the OP did not ask how to "disable F5", only how to detect it.

Comment: "I wrote a web counter, but **how can I disable F5** to prevent the number increase?"

Comment: @Jamie ⌘+R works like a charm for me on any site.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent *accidental* double-counting, you can use a [Cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) with an appropriate validity time.

Comment: As he said. If you want to prevent double-counting in general, you need to keep track of the user IPs as well.

Comment: This can be made arbitrarily complex, but because this is just a page counter and not, say, a voting service, it might be sufficient to "trust" the user. That's why I emphasized "accidental" in my answer.

Comment: I was referring to your answer with "as he said" and upvoted it too. I added my comment in case he needs the added complexity as it is not clear what the counter is used for.

Answer (score 2):

Use session cookies which expire when the session is over. That way you can test if a set cookie exists and only then run your code to update the counter. Take a look at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to see how to use the session cookies.